# Is there a way to set Tab Order in ASP.net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set up my tab order on the html side of my project.  How do I set the tab order.  Usually in visual basic, the option is in the menu bar under view/tab Order.  How do I do this in asp?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234704/tabbing-behavior-in-webforms

Comment: You can make `TabIndex="1" 
TabIndex="2" `

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add TabIndex="x" to each control that can receive focus where x is an integer indicating the desired order of the controls.

Answer (score 2):

As answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234704/tabbing-behavior-in-webforms):

e.g: 
You can set this with the TabIndex property on the ASP controls.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [TabIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tabindex.aspx) property

Comment: @Galwegian, shouldn't you close this as an exact duplicate?